# NA values when running function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe in R that has NA values in it. I would like to transform each variable into a Z score `x - mean(x) divided by std dev(x)` - is there a way to ignore the NA values when running my `~.funs`? Because when I run what I have now, I get NA values for all of my variables (I assume it's because I have NA values in my initial dataset)

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18262, 18293, 18322, 18353), class = "Date"), 
    a = c(NA, 1, 2, 3), b = c(NA, NA, 3, 5), c = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    4)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

data %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, .funs = ~(. - mean(.))/sd(.))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  Date           a     b     c
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-01-01    NA    NA    NA
2 2020-02-01    NA    NA    NA
3 2020-03-01    NA    NA    NA
4 2020-04-01    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: set `na.rm = TRUE` in both `mean` and `sd`.

Comment: `data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, .funs = ~(. - mean(., na.rm = TRUE))/sd(., na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: *"Scoped verbs (`_if`, `_at`, `_all`) have been superseded  by the use of `across()`"* (from `?mutate_if`) ... I think `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ (. - mean(., na.rm=TRUE)) / sd(., na.rm=TRUE)))` might be more "up-to-date" and recommended.